# Reference command name with dashes

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've recently discovered that Powershell functions are just named scriptblocks.  For example

```
function HelloWorld {
    Write-Output "Hello world"
}

$hw = $function:HelloWorld

& $hw
```

Will execute the HelloWorld method.

However, what I have not been able to figure out, is how to get a reference to a method that has a dash in it's name:

```
function Hello-World {
    Write-Output "Hello world"
}

$hw = $function:Hello-World

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:27
+     $hw = $function:Hello- <<<< World
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Any ideas?

I'm aware that I could do something like:

```
$hw = (Get-Item function:Hello-World).ScriptBlock
```

But it's a bit "noisy" and I like the $function syntax

Answer (score 7):

Doh!  I shoulda stuck with the [Programmer Problem Solving Sequence](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/10/22/programmer-problem-solving-sequence/)  and asked my co-workers *before* I posted to SO.  Looks like I should use:

```
$hw = ${function:Hello-World}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Executing ${function:Get-Item} gives nothing

Comment: Get-Item isn't a function, it's a cmdlet, so ${function:Get-Item} won't return anything

Answer (score 4):

As well as using `$script = ${function:hello-world}` there is also `$script = get-content function:hello-world`. '$' as a unary operator equates to using `get-content` (alias is `gc`)

Comment: Ah! That's a nice factoid about "$"..  I feel like all my scripts are gonna look like jQuery soon!

Comment: @x0n This isn't working for me. Executing ${function:Get-Item} gives nothing.

Comment: Could this be because Get-Item is a commandlet, yet x0n is talking about function references?

Comment: Correct - get-item is a binary cmdlet. It is not logically on the function drive.

Answer (score 2):

To invoke the function all you need to do is to call it by its name.

```
PS> Hello-World
Hello world
```

`${function:Hello-World}` is the way to get the code of the function. Here's another way:

```
Get-Command Hello-World | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
```