# Invoking callbacks from PowerShell functions

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add some callback capabilities to a PowerShell function but I want to be able to define the behaviour of the callbacks outside of the function definition, so basically a very simple Inversion of Control for PowerShell.

I'm trying to be as backward compatible as is practical, and this is what I've come up with so far (error handling removed for brevity):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

function Invoke-DoSomethingMethod
{
    param
    (
        [hashtable] $Callbacks
    )
    $CallBacks["OnStarted"].Invoke();
    for( $i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++ )
    {
        # ... do something here ...
        $CallBacks["OnProgress"].Invoke($i * 10);
    }
    $CallBacks["OnFinished"].Invoke();
}

$myHostCallbacks = @{
    "OnStarted"  = { write-host "started" }
    "OnProgress" = { write-host "processing $($args[0])%" }
    "OnFinished" = { write-host "finished" }
}

$myFileCallbacks = @{
    "OnStarted"  = { Add-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" "started" }
    "OnProgress" = { Add-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" "processing $($args[0])%" }
    "OnFinished" = { Add-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" "finished" }
}

$myWebCallbacks = @{
    "OnStarted"  = { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org/OnStarted" }
    "OnProgress" = { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org/OnProgress/$($args[0])" }
    "OnFinished" = { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org/OnFinish" }
}

Invoke-DoSomethingMethod -Callbacks $myHostCallbacks;
```

When run, this outputs the following:

```
c:\temp>powershell .\callbacks.ps1

started
processing 10%
processing 20%
processing 30%
processing 40%
processing 50%
processing 60%
processing 70%
processing 80%
processing 90%
processing 100%
finished
```

Without using external modules or C# code, is there a more idomatic way of doing this with PowerShell that doesn't rely on matching up the magic strings for callback names and the order of $args[] parameters? (Preferrably compatible with version 2.0).

Cheers,

Mike

**Update**

For some context, my Invoke-DoSomething function is part of a CI build framework
(https://github.com/ASOS/OctopusStepTemplateCi) which is currently hard-coded to send TeamCity service messages using Write-Host during the build process.

We're interested in supporting other build server products so I'm investigating a way to abstract out the various interactions with the build server into user-definable callbacks like "OnBuildStarted", "OnBuildStepFailed", etc, like you might do with an IoC framework in C#.

This would make it easier to ship support for new build servers from within the project, and also for users to write callbacks for build servers which don't come out-of-the-box.

This might help give a flavour of what I'm trying to do:

```
function Invoke-BuildScript
{
    param( [hashtable] $Callbacks )
    $CallBacks["OnBuildStarted"].Invoke();
    ... build script here ...
    $CallBacks["OnBuildFinished"].Invoke();
}

$teamCityCallbacks = @{
    "OnBuildStarted"  = { write-host "started" }
    "OnBuildFinished" = { write-host "finished" }
    "OnBuildError"    = { write-host "error '$($args[0])'" }
}

$jenkinsCallbacks = @{
    "OnBuildStarted"  = { ... }
    "OnBuildFinished" = { ... }
    "OnBuildError"    = { ... }
}

Invoke-BuildScript -Callbacks $teamCityCallbacks;
```

Comment: Considering that all member resolution of PowerShell is at runtime, matching up magic strings isn't really better or worse than matching up other member names -- it's all magic, and it all won't blow up if you get it wrong until the interpreter actually hits the line. You could experiment with empty objects and `Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod`, but I recall this gets rather finicky rather fast. Still, it might clean up the syntax a bit.

Comment: I wonder can you do anything with function pointers ala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489060/reference-command-name-with-dashes

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully clear on what you want to do, but `OnStarted`, `OnProgress`, `OnFinished` kinda-sorta seems to align with the PowerShell pipeline concepts of `Begin`, `Process`, `End`.

If you have a multi-part pipeline, they may all implement 1 or more of these blocks.

In a single pipeline, *each element's* `Begin` block gets executed first, then each element's `Process` block gets executed *once for each item in the pipeline* (later elements can be skipped if the previous element doesn't send any output to the pipeline), and finally *each element's* `End` block gets executed.

The easiest way to see this without writing your own function is with `ForEach-Object` which, while most often used with only a `Process` block, can also run `Begin` and `End` blocks.

Demonstration (with a single user-defined function):

```
function Invoke-MyPipeline {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $Value
)

    Begin {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Begin Invoke-MyPipeline' -Verbose
    }

    Process {
        $Value * 2
    }

    End {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'End Invoke-MyPipeline' -Verbose
    }
}

1..10 | 
    Invoke-MyPipeline | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin { 
        Write-Verbose -Message 'ForEach (1) Begin' -Verbose
    } -Process {
        "~$_~"
    } -End {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'ForEach (1) End' -Verbose
    } |
    ForEach-Object -Begin { 
        Write-Verbose -Message 'ForEach (2) Begin' -Verbose
    } -Process {
        "@$_@"
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500  # watch this effect on the whole pipeline
    } -End {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'ForEach (2) End' -Verbose
    }
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVNda8IwFH33V1xcwXYQqYU9DsShsAeZILiHMSS2tzZbmpQkTsacf73rl67OCmXbfQi5N@fec3JCErlFpSPkPE0hi3AjfMOkgHvxJl@RTN9nLEHOBMJHJwc83cUBRzNiImBibTvPRTWhisZ2sS1AszxHg8peUL7BiZLxYc6tZdQGq748rAJSpE6xHk9GuGai4j3Eo2IGyQLVSmoEMkWt6RqhV2LPVPfggD1O@TwlmSnpZ0N@0JSi4Bq8S31jEbSUliPbC6vRDPr9gQu7b87zR6kdTqQaUz8iD6sX9A2Qyj1opbFqBnvglLY36QPSbFZ3by333TquvTl14qyrkXb3z3f0fnPHobUcdk9Kc0OVIXOOmGQsjHOm0Zci0HDjugBXsKUmozMR04BhmAvOPpaJELaR5AhJ9Yh/NM67aFwnTb8A) (but paste it into ISE to see the effect of the timing delays)

So what does this have to do with you?

Instead of naming the script blocks, you can just take them as an array. Then you can interpret them to same way that `ForEach-Object` does (if there's 1 scriptblock, it's `Process`, if there are 2, the first is `Begin`, the second is `Process`, if there are 3, it's `Begin`, `Process`, `End`).

`ForEach-Object` also accepts additional scriptblocks. It manages them a bit strangely, I think. If there's 1 extra, it (the 4th) will be treated as a second `End` block. If there's 2+ extra, then the *N-1* extras are treated as extra `Process` *and* `End` blocks, and the *last* extra is treated as an extra `End` block only.:

```
1,2,3|%{write-verbose 'A' -Verbose}{$_}{write-verbose 'B' -Verbose}{Write-Verbose 'Extra1' -Verbose}{Write-Verbose 'Extra2' -Verbose}{Write-Verbose 'Extra3' -Verbose}{Write-Verbose 'Extra4' -Verbose}
```

### "Ok but, how is this useful?"

Because instead of reimplementing these rules (or your own), you can just let `ForEach-Object` do it for you:

```
function Invoke-DoSomethingMethod {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [hashtable[]]
    $ScriptBlock # renaming to follow PowerShell conventions
)
    1..10 | 
        ForEach-Object -Process { $_*10 } | # this replaces your foreach
        ForEach-Object @ScriptBlock  # Callbacks invoked here
}

$myHostCallbacks = @(
     { write-host "started" }
    ,{ write-host "processing $_%" } # bonus $_ usage
    ,{ write-host "finished" }
)

Invoke-DoSomethingMethod -ScriptBlock $myHostCallbacks
```

### Bonus

You get to use `$_`, which is a common and well-understood pattern in PowerShell, without doing anything extra.

### Note

You can still accept it as a hashtable and the same code will work *if* the hashtable keys match the parameters of `ForEach-Object`, which may be less flexible in this case.

Comment: Ah sorry, the names of the pseudo-events were badly chosen. In my specific case, the callbacks are for logging messages from CI build scripts, but I want to support multiple build server products, so instead of hard-coding functions like Write-TeamCityServiceMessage or Write-JenkinsMessage I'd rather pass the function a bag of callbacks for "OnBuildStarted", "OnBuildStepStarted", "OnUnitTestResults", etc and let the callbacks interface with the build server.

Answer (score 2):

Not so much an answer to my original question about IoC in PowerShell, but I managed to at least hide the magic strings and callback parameters behind some wrapper cmdlets so the callback structure becomes an opaque type:

```
# knowledge of magic strings and parameter orders confined to here

function Invoke-OnStartedCallback
{
    param
    (
        [hashtable] $Callbacks
    )
    Invoke-Callback -Callbacks $CallBacks -Name "OnStarted";
}

function Invoke-OnProgressCallback
{
    param
    (
        [hashtable] $Callbacks,
        [int]       $PercentComplete
    )
    Invoke-Callback -Callbacks $CallBacks -Name "OnProgress" -Parameters @( $PercentComplete );
}

function Invoke-OnFinishedCallback
{
    param
    (
        [hashtable] $Callbacks
    )
    Invoke-Callback -Callbacks $CallBacks -Name "OnFinished";
}

function New-DoSomethingCallbacks
{
    param
    (
        [scriptblock] $OnStarted,
        [scriptblock] $OnProgress,
        [scriptblock] $OnFinished
    )
    return @{
        "OnStarted"  = $OnStarted
        "OnProgress" = $OnProgress
        "OnFinished" = $OnFinished
    };
}
```

The rest of the code can then be written as:

```
# no knowledge of magic strings below here

function Invoke-DoSomethingMethod
{
    param
    (
        [hashtable] $Callbacks
    )
    Invoke-OnStartedCallback $CallBacks;
    for( $i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++ )
    {
        # ... do something ...
        Invoke-OnProgressCallback $CallBacks -PercentComplete ($i * 10);
    }
    Invoke-OnFinishedCallback $CallBacks;
}


$myHostCallbacks = New-DoSomethingCallbacks -OnStarted  { write-host "started" } `
                                            -OnProgress { write-host "processing $($args[0])%" } `
                                            -OnFinished { write-host "finished" };

$myFileCallbacks = New-DoSomethingCallbacks -OnStarted  { Add-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" "started" } `
                                            -OnProgress { Add-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" "processing $($args[0])%" } `
                                            -OnFinished { Add-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" "finished" };

$myWebCallbacks  = New-DoSomethingCallbacks -OnStarted  { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org/OnStarted" } `
                                            -OnProgress { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org/OnProgress/$($args[0])" } `
                                            -OnFinished { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org/OnFinish" };

Invoke-DoSomethingMethod -Callbacks $myHostCallbacks;
```

with a small helper cmdlet:

```
function Invoke-Callback
{
    param
    (
        [hashtable] $Callbacks,
        [string]    $Name,
        [object[]]  $Parameters
    )
    if( -not $Callbacks.ContainsKey($Name) )
    {
        return;
    }
    $callback = $Callbacks[$Name];
    if( $null -eq $callback )
    {
        return;
    }
    if( $null -eq $Parameters )
    {
        $callback.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        $callback.Invoke($Parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is what you are looking for. Perhaps I also misunderstood the question.

```
function Invoke-DoSomethingMethod ($OnStarted, $OnProgress, $OnFinished) {
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $OnStarted
    for ( $i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++ ) {
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $OnProgress
    }
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $OnFinished
}

$OnStartedSb = [ScriptBlock]::Create('write-host "started"')
$OnProgressSb = [ScriptBlock]::Create('write-host "processing $($i * 10)%"')
$OnFinishedSb = [ScriptBlock]::Create('write-host "finished"')
Invoke-DoSomethingMethod -OnStarted $OnStartedSb -OnProgress $OnProgressSb -OnFinished $OnFinishedSb
```